# SOAP Failure for Certain Installations

Tags: soap

Up front, please know that my knowledge here could be quite lacking...

We have written a small app that displays a custom button on a related list and that button triggers (via SOAP) a request back to the SF server.

Until now, we have not seen any issues with it, nor have any clients that have installed the app.

We currently have one client, however, that installed the app and has it working currently in a "developer sandbox on c2" however upon installation in "a full sandbox on cs10" they have been getting the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR 405

Problem accessing /services/Soap/package/ourpackage/oursoaphandler. Reason:

GET not supported, this is a SOAP service, please use POST.
```

The 'ourpackage/oursoaphandler' is filler to replace our details.

I included the quotes above about the two environments on the off chance that this could somehow be related to the servers themselves.

Has anyone seen this type of issue before? Any suggestions for what I should be looking at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain that the service you are calling is using SOAP? It isn't a RESTful service by chance?

SOAP requests always([*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26339467/54026)) use a POST request to send the XML body. Encoding that into a GET query string would run into problems with length.

If your Apex class using using the `webservice` keyword then it will be a "proper" [SOAP web service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_web_services_methods.htm?search_text=webservice) and will expose a WSDL. The WSDL will include the endpoint address URL to call it at. E.g.

> https://na5.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/YourPackageNamespace/YourApexClassName

However, if you are using `@RestResource` and `@HttpPost` then it is a [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_annotations_list.htm) masquerading as a SOAP based service.

That you a receiving an error message about a GET request might also indicate a problem with the calling code. Are you using Wsdl2Apex, or hand crafting your own Apex HttpRequest?